# In Quorum, Does contract resides on all the nodes or a majority subset of the nodes?

Tags: contract-invocation, quorum

"A contract in the sense of Solidity is a collection of code (its functions) and data (its state) that resides at a specific
address on the Ethereum blockchain." - Solidity Documentation

In Quorum, Does the deployed contract resides on all the nodes or a majority subset of the nodes? Say 3/4? And when a transaction is sent to a node, it is executed by one node and the result of the state change is propagated. OR the execution is done by all the nodes so the state change is immediately updated.

Answer (score 1):

In Quorum, there are 2 states: public and private. Contracts that are public reside on all nodes that are up to date (block height) -- same behavior as Ethereum. Contracts that are private sit in private state and only exist on the nodes party to the contract creation txn.